# Is a "transposition-table" tag relevant enough to introduce it?

Tags: discussion

So far, I have never created a tag. I notice that a general source of confusing in chess related questions is that people generally mean "transposition table" when they write "hashtable" or "hashmap".

Do you think that a transposition table tag is too specific? How do you decide when to add a new tag?

Background: The difference is that a "transposition table" is more like a cache, but a hash table is a more general data structure.

Example questions:

- [C: Easy and fast hash table for chess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27001177/783510)
- [Fast Hashtable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14227311/783510)

Comment: It'd probably be useful if you could include some questions which would get the new tag in your post, especially for those not aware of any "chess related questions" that it would fit for.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes, I updated my post